# In Socket.io, how to get the stored cookie information?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

In node application using express, I have stored cookie information. Now I need to get the stored cookie information in socket.io. How can I get this?

```
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {

        res.cookie('cookieName','1', { maxAge: 50000, httpOnly: true });
    });

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

     //here i need to access the cookie.how can i do this

    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i found the answer.The below code will get the cookie information.

```
     io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

          var cookie=socket.handshake.headers['cookie'];

     });
```

Comment: how can you parse this? it gives some sort of un-parsable JSON string that starts with `s:j:`. what is that??

Comment: it gives me like this; io=pYb2vzAd8wWW......  , it is different from my cookies information ? What can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the socket.request object provided after connection event.

To quote the docs = "A getter proxy that returns the reference to the request that originated the underlying engine.io Client. Useful for accessing request headers such as Cookie or User-Agent."

I think this feature was not in the versoin 0.*, it's shiped only with 1 and above.

This link for the detailed docs wich is a kind of hidden = https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#socketrequest